# Does CouchDB distinguish between floats/ints/strings?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I need to optimize disk usage and amount of data transferred during replication with my CouchDB instance. Does storing numerical data as int/floats instead of as string make a difference to file storage and or during http requests? I've read that JSON treats everything as strings, but newer JSON specs make use of different datatypes (float/int/boolean). What about for PouchDB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CouchDB stores JSON data in native JSON types, so ints and floats are actual number types when serialised to disk. But I doubt you save much disk space over when that wouldn’t be the case. The replication protocol uses JSON and the internal encoding has no effect on this.

Answer (score 1):

PouchDB in WebSQL and Sqlite store your document as string (I don't know what IndexedDb). 
So to optimize disk usage, just keep less data. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually need to know about IndexedDB, since my deployments are all Android.

Comment: You can check it in your browser or debug your app.

Why IndexedDB? Why not WebSQL? WebSQL more faster than IndexedDB

Comment: According to this: https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html - IndexedDB is the preferred database.

Comment: Just because the library prefers (defaults to) something doesn't mean you should. I believe that decision was made because WebSQL is deprecated, it is (however) also faster. Also, if *all* deploys are android, are they Cordova? In that case, sqlite is the default.